# Is subsection generation O(n^4)

Tags: algorithm, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, big-o

When I say template matching, I'm referring to finding occurrences of a small image (the template) in a larger image.

The OpenCV library provides the trivial solution, that slides the template over every possible location of the image. While this implementation provides translation invariance, it provides no stretching/scaling invariance. To get stretch *and* translation invariance, one would need to stretch the template (or shrink the main image) until iteratively, running the original template check over the image. This increases complexity to O(S * n^2) where S is the number of different stretches one does - if one want's to check every possible resolution, the overall complexity is O(n^4). Effectively, you generate O(n^4) subsections and check if they're equal to the template.

From what I was taught, Image Segmentation Networks do just this - however, instead of using the basic template matching (i.e. checking the pixels match) the generated subsection is put through a classifier network - so this would be more expensive than standard templating.

[image]

My question is, are my calculations correct - for complete subsection generation, is the complexity O(n^4) and is there really no better algorithm for generating these subsections - used by both image detection algorithms?

Comment: @Emma That's the basic (O(n^2)) algorithm, which includes the template check O(m^2). The O(n^4) doesn't take into account iterating through each pixel of the template, because this is specific to basic template matching, but doesn't transfer to using a neural network to do more complex classification. Here I'm more concerned with the subsection generation - which is shared by both algorithms

Comment: @Emma How would wavelet transformations apply here?

Comment: Java, Python, Javascript or C++. I had thought wavelets were used for spectral analysis of signals, like fourier transforms, or also for image compression / denoising

Comment: Still trying to understand how they work here, do you know of any videos explaining?

Comment: The video shows usages I was talking about, time-frequency analysis. How does it apply here?

Comment: this question is only about sub-sectioning, feature detection is a completely different problem

Comment: I don't understand your trail of thought